# Cannot see final result of canvas merge with js

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm merging two images, but result is empty, I've following function:

```
function merge_avatar_flag(avatar_url,country) {
          var flag = new Image('allflags/'+ country.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('_') +'.png');
          var avatar = new Image(avatar_url);
          var img = new Image();
          avatar.onload = function() {
            flag.onload = function() {
              var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
              var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
              ctx.drawImage(flag, 0, 0);
              ctx.drawImage(avatar, 0, 0);
              img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
              return img;
            }
          }
        }
```

And the result is merged like this:

```
$("#changeAvatar").append(merge_avatar_flag(random_avatar,country));
```

Nothing gets added.

Anything obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: I guess there must be some alpha configuration for merging the image...

Comment: In your code above, if the flag loads before the avatar, your code won't get hit; you don't define `flag.onload` until the avatar loads.  Possible quick fixes are not starting the flag load until the avatar is done, or un-nest the `onload` functions, and give each one a check to see if both are loaded, and run the merge if they are.

Comment: @Hylianpuffball wait, both images need to load at some point right? so why does it matter? Doesn't onload simply check if image is loaded?

Comment: @Hylianpuffball I tried both, and I've noticed that in neither case onload is not fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must fully load all images before you try to drawImage them:

After the images are all fully loaded you can combine the images into an img element like this:

```
$("#combine").click(function(){
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");        
    canvas.width=imgs[0].width;
    canvas.height=imgs[0].height;
    ctx.drawImage(imgs[0],0,0);     // imgs[0] is the flag
    ctx.drawImage(imgs[1],0,0);     // imgs[1] is the avatar
    $("#changeAvatar").attr("src",canvas.toDataURL());
});
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/m2DWP/

[image]

Code example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #combine{display:none;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var imageURLs=[];  // put the paths to your images here
    var imagesOK=0;
    var imgs=[];
    imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stack1/norwayFlag.jpg");
    imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stack1/avatar.png");
    loadAllImages(start);

    function loadAllImages(callback){
        for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
            var img = new Image();
            imgs.push(img);
            img.onload = function(){ 
                imagesOK++; 
                if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                    callback();
                }
            };
            img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
            img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
            img.src = imageURLs[i];
        }      
    }

    function start(){
        $("#combine").show();
    }

    $("#combine").click(function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");        
        canvas.width=imgs[0].width;
        canvas.height=imgs[0].height;
        ctx.drawImage(imgs[0],0,0);
        ctx.drawImage(imgs[1],0,0);
        $("#changeAvatar").attr("src",canvas.toDataURL());
    });

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <button id="combine">Combine</button><br>
    <img id="changeAvatar">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Strange... I could not see your answer until now and I got an error when trying to edit mine http://imgur.com/8cS8YyO Even SO has some hickups.. (or maybe the net is..)

Comment: Yep...I was re-routed an SO page that indicates it was doing maintenance.  SO seems to be back now.  Rock-on!!!

Comment: btw, this was not a real problem. I rearranged loading onloads and it still didn't help. Problem was that when I was doing append with jquery function didn't have result yet. So append was receiving undefined. Doing append from within function helped, but obviously defeated the point of reusable function.